# How to create N x M x ... matrix in javascript dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I am working on something in javascript where I need to create a matrix with dynamic dimensions depending upon an array.

For example, I have an array with `[3, 5, 6]` - now I want to create a matrix dynamically that is 3 x 5 x 6, and in this matrix, all the values are initialized to 0.

I can seem to find a way to do this dynamically depending upon my initial array values. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Just use a recursive function with for loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion.

```js
function createMatrix(dimensions) {
  return dimensions.length === 1 ? Array(dimensions[0]).fill(0) : Array.from({
    length: dimensions[0]
  }, () => createMatrix(dimensions.slice(1)));
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(createMatrix([3, 5, 6])));
```

Comment: is there a way i can do this without arrow notation?

Comment: @SnG Yes, you can use `function(){return createMatrix(dimensions.slice(1))}`

Comment: this is an unrelated question, but in my example I can have N dimensions based on the input. Is there a way I can programmatically index the N dimensional matrix given an array of indexes?

Comment: @SnG `indexes.reduce((acc,i)=>acc[i], matrix)`

Comment: thanks @iota ...last Q :D - what about setting a value in a matrix given the indexes to set for ?

Comment: Get the second last element you need using reduce, and set the last index on that.

Answer (score 3):

A recursive function that uses `Array.from` will do the trick.

```js
const makeMatrix = (length, ...restDimensionLengths) => Array.from(
  { length },
  () => restDimensionLengths.length ? makeMatrix(...restDimensionLengths) : 0
);

console.log(makeMatrix(2, 3, 5));
```

Comment: is there a way i can do this without arrow notation?

Comment: Just use `function() { return` instead of `() =>` ??